# Is there a name for Symbolab's Latex editor?

Tags: editors

https://www.symbolab.com/

The one for symbolab converts your typed characters into a latex equation and autoformats it as you go. Is there a name for something like this? Where can I find a similar engine or is this proprietary of symbolab?

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about either system but looking at the page source shows that it is using the open source mathquill editor

http://mathquill.com/